# Error 1004 occurs: "application-defined or object-defined"

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to check through all images in my userform and check values in certain cells in worksheet. Then based on the value change picture of image object to one of 19 (i1 to i19). To not check each image i wanted to loop that process. All image objects have names from slot_1 to slot_42. It should work but it is not. So any ideas ?
And don't ask why aa : /

Error 1004 occurs: "application-defined or object-defined"

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
name = Sheets("Player Data").Cells(2, 1).Value
inventory.Caption = name & "' s inventory"
name_label_inv.Caption = name
item_info_label.Visible = False
item_info_label.Caption = " "
Dim aa
For aa = 1 To 42 Step 1
    If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, 11).Value = 0 Then
    Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture(vbNullString)
    GoTo line1
    End If

        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 1 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_exp_book.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 2 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_silver_coin.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 3 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_gold_ingot.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 4 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_heal_hp_1.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 5 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_heal_mp_1.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 6 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_heal_hp_2.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 7 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_weapon_1.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 8 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_weapon_2.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 9 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_weapon_3.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 10 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_arrow.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 11 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_weapon_4.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 12 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_weapon_5.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 13 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_shield_1.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 14 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_armor_helmet_1.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 15 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_armor_chest_1.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 16 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_armor_ring_1.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 17 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_wild_1.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 18 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_wild_2.jpg")
        End If
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(aa + 1, l2).Value = 19 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & aa).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_key.jpg")
        End If
line1:
Next aa
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Unrelated to the error message, but instead of that long series of `If` statements you could have an array of path strings.

Comment: Also, `GoTo line2` is redundant because `line2` immediately follows this statement. It's best to avoid using `GoTo` altogether except for error handling purposes.

Comment: even after i removed line 2 still  nothing. And Bigben  "Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()"
 is highlighted